# Calling Stop-VM "safely" after windows upgrade turns PC off during "Don't turn off your PC" steps

Tags: powershell, hyper-v

`Stop-VM` will shut down a Hyper-V VM. It is generally safe as (by default) it won't shut down the machine if a user is logged in with unsaved changes, which is great.

However, I noticed that when logging in for the first time after a windows upgrade, you'll get a slideshow from windows that says things like

> Hi
>
> We've got some updates for your PC
>
> This might take several minutes-Don't turn off your PC

If I call Stop-VM while this slideshow is running, windows will shut down well before the slideshow has ended. I realize there is a minimum duration for this slideshow.

What is going on during this slideshow and how do I know when it is safe to shut down? Can i just assume Stop-VM is well-behaved here?

Comment: I believe during this first time user profile etc. settings are being loaded in the newly upgraded OS, which takes this much of time.

Comment: Even better: how could you detect a VM is in this state from Powershell, so your script could handle it automatically?

Comment: Yeah, that would be great. I've done some more experiments and am getting more confident that I'm ok, but still... for example, after installing windows updates (not an upgrade), the machine reboots and is on the screen where it says installing updates xx%, do not turn off. If I call Stop-VM at that time, it will not shut down the machine until the update process completes.

Comment: There may be a registry key that exists during that phase.  That's usually how MS handles those things

Comment: Yeah, I would expect so, that's a good point. One worry I have is it seems likely the registry key is cleared when the login starts, based on the fact that if I shutdown and start the machine back up during the slideshow, I don't see the slideshow again. Maybe I'll try to set the VM up with multiple accounts so I can easily get sysinternals tools to trace registry accesses while that is going on... It would also give me insight into what else is going on during that first logon post upgrade.

Comment: I looked a bit with procmon during a new user logon (not post upgrade, but they both show the same slideshow, and I expect the things happening are similar). The slideshow is "FirstLogonAnim.exe", and takes about 20 seconds at minimum. There are 7000+ events just from this process in procmon, and I looked for a few minutes, but didn't see anything telling.

Comment: I was curious if having a scheduled task to run at login might help, if it happened to wait until the login slideshow was "complete" to start. It does not, so that's not a viable technique.